# Get value after string slash from current url javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, url

i have a current page url that looks like this:

```
http://localhost/admin/namespace_module/yeezy/index/test_id/5/key/23123asda/
```

the url can be dynamic but always contain ***/test_id/value/*** , first i want to check if the **/test_id/** is exist in my current url:

```
window.location.href
```

then i need to retrieve the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it with the regular expression in combination with `.test()` to check and `.match()` to extract the number:

```js
var url = "http://localhost/admin/namespace_module/yeezy/index/test_id/5/key/23123asda/"; // window.locatioin.href;

if(/test_id\/[0-9]+/.test(url)){
   console.log(url.match(/test_id\/[0-9]+/)[0].match(/[0-9]+/)[0]);
   //--test_id/5---------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^----5--^^^^^^^^^^^^
}  //--output-----------------------------------output-----------
```

Comment: The downside to this method is that it is not so efficient. Up to three times a regular expression is executed, while it can be done with one regular expression execution.

Answer (score 1):

Use `RegExp#test` method.

```
if(/\/test_id\//.test(window.location.href)){

}
```

or use `String#indexOf` method.

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf('/test_id/') > -1){

}
```

Comment: then how can i retrieve the value after the slash?

Comment: @IdhamChoudry : `window.location.href.split('/test_id/').pop()`

Answer (score 1):

To get the number after testing for the pattern, do:

```
var match = window.location.href.match(/\/test_id\/(\d+)/);
if (match) {
    // pattern is OK, get the number
    var num = +match[1];
    // ...
}
```